# Como aproveitar a consulta em dois relatórios de layouts distintos?

Tags: jasper-reports, dry

Tenho dois relatórios em Jasper para visões diferentes sobre a mesma massa de dados. É tanto que os parâmetros e a consulta são exatamente iguais.

Existe algum método, inerente ao Jasper Reports, que permita eu escrever essa consulta/esses parâmetros apenas uma única vez e aproveitar em ambos `.jrxml`s? Ou devo fazer eu mesmo algum método de substituição textual para permitir isso?

Comment: Como você faz os seus relatórios hoje com relação a fonte de dados ? Você coloca as consultas dentro de cada relatório ?

Comment: @hebertrfreitas sim, desse jeito mesmo. Consulta dentro do `jrxml`

Answer (score 0):

O jasperreports possui o conceito de DataSources, onde você pode montar a fonte de dados do seu relatório a partir de vários formatos e enviá-la para os seus relatórios.

Você precisa executar um código que retorne alguma implementação da interface [JRDataSource](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRDataSource.html)

Existem algumas implementações desta classe dependendo de como você deseja passar seus dados, seguem exemplos:

1. [JRResultSetDataSource](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRResultSetDataSource.html) Caso você queira trabalhar com um ResultSet
2. [JRBeanCollectionDataSource](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/data/JRBeanCollectionDataSource.html) Caso você queira passar uma Collection qualquer como List, Set, etc
3. [JRXlsDataSource](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/data/JRXlsDataSource.html) Caso você queira usar um arquivo do Excel como fonte de dados.

Basicamente, ao invés de montar a consultar no relatorio e mandar ele executar a consulta você passar a fonte de dados para o método fillReport, segue exemplo:

```
InputStream isDesignRelatorio = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("path/to/report.jasper");
JRDataSource dataSource = new JRResultSetDataSource(this.getResultSet());
JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(isDesignRelatorio,this.getParametros(), dataSource);
ByteArrayOutputStream pdfStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  

JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
exporter.setExporterInput(SimpleExporterInput.getInstance(Arrays.asList(print)));
exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(pdfStream));
SimplePdfExporterConfiguration configuration = new SimplePdfExporterConfiguration() ;
configuration.setCreatingBatchModeBookmarks(true);
exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);
exporter.exportReport();
```

Algumas observações sobre este trecho de código:

Este exemplo assume que você tem um arquivo jrxml já compilado em formato .jasper, eu compilo o relatório pela ferramenta de design para que o código não "perca tempo" fazendo isso, no entanto você também pode optar por compilar em tempo de execução.
Neste caso acrescente uma linha compilando o relatório, por exemplo:

```
 JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(isDesignRelatorio);
```

O método `this.getResultSet()` é para representar a sua fonte de dados que neste caso seria um ResultSet, mas como expliquei anteriormente pode ser até uma Collection de um DTO montado por você ou até mesmo uma entidade do banco.
Neste caso troque a implmentação do data source de `new JRResultSetDataSource(this.getResultSet());` para algo como `new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(this.getCollection());`

Este exemplo escreve a saída da exportação em um `ByteArrayOutputStream`, caso você esteja trabalhando com um sistema web pode escrever diretamente no outputstream.

Também existe a possibilidade de gerar a saída em um arquivo físico, basta explorar as formas de exportação.